# Implementation of "show" for function

Tags: haskell

I would like to implement the `show` method for (binary) functions and make it able to distingish endofunctions `(a -> a)`.

Something like the pseudo-haskell code:

```
instance Show (a->b) where
    show fun = "<<Endofunction>>" if a==b
    show fun = "<<Function>>" if a\=b
```

How can I distinguish the two cases?

Comment: That wouldn't be a good `Show` instance at all. You should rather write something like `isEndo :: (a->b) -> Bool`, and then use a simple guard to create the suitable text where you want it.

Comment: Is `const 3` an endofunction or a function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to enable some extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}
module FunShow where

instance Show ((->) a a) where
    show _ = "<<Endofunction>>"

instance Show ((->) a b) where
    show _ = "<<Function>>"
```

You need `OverlappingInstances` since the instance `a -> b` also matches endofunctions, so there's overlap, and you need `FlexibleInstances` because the language standard mandates that the type variables in instance declarations are distinct.

```
*FunShow> show not
"<<Endofunction>>"
*FunShow> show fst
"<<Function>>"
*FunShow> show id
"<<Endofunction>>"
```